# Symfony3 - Extend namespace

Tags: authentication, namespaces, symfony

I have the following directory structure in my symfony3 structure:

```
src
    AppBundle
        AppBundle.php
        Entity
            User
                User.php
                UserRepository.php
```

On top of my User.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\User;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\User\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface {
```

and it tells me:

```
undefined constant User
```

Is there any way extending the namespace?

Thanks and Greetings!

EDIT:

occurrence of "user":

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: admin
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: username

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
```

Comment: is the error on the same line as class keyword?

Comment: its on the line where namespace is defined, why?

Comment: cannot see why it should be incorrect at all

Comment: i am using phpstorm as IDE. when i type in console: php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force . it prints: Class 'AppBundle\Entity\User' does not exist . any idea´s ?

Comment: look somewhere else where you have it, relation?

Comment: i just mentioned it in my security.xml, i edited my question above. can you refer to it?

Comment: AppBundle:User is probably incorrect

Comment: worked with AppBundle:User\User .. strange...

Comment: The `AppBundle:EntityClassName` notation refers to the `Entity` namespace of your bundle. If you want to use subdirectories (and therefore subnamespaces) there, you need to specifiy them too.

Comment: so i did it correctly or do i need to specify it in an other way?

Answer (score 3):

`AppBundle:User` alias with your configuration resolves to `AppBundle\Entity\User` class, which obviously doesn't exist. Either use the full namespace `AppBundle\Entity\User\User` or the `AppBundle:User\User` alias.

This is how auto-mapping works. It looks for classes in the Entity folder in each bundle.

See the [doctrine reference docs for more](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).